# Make sure Sonatype Nexus P2 Proxy Repository stays available when the remote repository shutdown

Tags: nexus, p2

Whe have a Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.14.4-03 with a few p2 proxy repositories for some month now. Back then I tested if it still works when the internet connection is broken and it did. We want to be independent from the internet.

Today we had some problems with a Repository for which I got yesterday a notificaton that it is auto-blocked. Yesterday it worked and today not.

Proxy repository  "eclipse releases luna" (repoId=p2_eclipse_releases_luna) was auto-blocked.

I looked in the Configuration from that Repository and noticed some configurations with 1440 min (24 h).

- Repository ID: p2_eclipse_releases_luna
- Repository name: eclipse releases luna
- Repository Type: proxy
- Provider: P2
- Format: p2
- Repository Policy: Mixed
- Default Local Storage Location: file:/C:/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/p2_eclipse_releases_luna/
- Override Local Storage Location:
- Remote Repository Access
- Remote Storage Location: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/
- Download Remote Indexes: False
- Auto Blocking Enabled: True
- File Content Validation: True
- Checksum Policy: Ignore
- Authentication (optional): [ ]
- Access Settings
- Allow File Browsing: True
- Include in Search: False
- Publish URL: True
- Not Found Cache TTL: 1440 minutes
- Artifact Max Age: -1 minutes
- Metadata Max Age: 1440 minutes
- Item Max Age: 1440 minutes
- Http Request Settings (optional): [ ]

Should I change Not Found Cache TTL, Metadata Max Age and Item Max Age some or all of them to -1?

Comment: Auto-blocked means the remote isn't reachable on your network, it's nothing to worry about.  Check the nexus log files to see why.  Locally cached content will still be available when repository is auto-blocked. It will be automatically unblocked when the network issue is resolved.

Comment: the problem was that it was not available (resolving my target platfrom against the nexus did not work) - yesterday it worked and today not. Roughly after 24h when I got the first auto-blocked message.